# How to cancel summation term that is multiplied by an equal summation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation

I have to demonstrate how to get from this initial equation:

$c = \frac{1}{1+R(1-\xi_t)}\cdot \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\left[ (1-\tau)w_t(i)n_t(i)+ \frac{1}{N} \left( \tau \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{w}{(1+\pi)^i}n_i + m_t - \frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi} \right) \right]$

to this following:

$c = \frac{1}{1+R(1-\xi_t)}\cdot \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\left[ w_t(i)n_t(i)+ m_t - \frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi} \right]$

Although it seems pretty straight forward, I'm stucked on canceling the second summation $\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}$ in parenthesis that's multiplied by the same summation with a constant $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}$ out of the square brackets and also that inside the parenthesis I have $\frac{w}{(1+\pi)^i}n_i$ instead of just $w(i)n(i)$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with linear algebra. Why would you use that tag?

Comment: What is with the misuse of dummy variables?? Because your second summation is inside the first, the variable $i$ has two different possible meanings inside it. NEVER use the same variable to mean two different things in the same context. Please fix it.

Comment: This doesn't look right, and not just because of the ambiguity of the notation. Whether $$\tau \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{w}{(1+\pi)^i}n_i + m_t - \frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi}$$ means $$\tau \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\left( \frac{w}{(1+\pi)^i}n_i + m_t - \frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi}\right)$$ or $$\left(\tau \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{w}{(1+\pi)^i}n_i \right)+ m_t - \frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi},$$ it just doesn't add up. Where did these equations come from, and are you sure they are both correct? What makes you think that?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm sorry, it was my error when finishing the post.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks. I understand your comment, you're right. Unfortunately the equations are from an economics paper and I took them exactly as they are presented.

Comment: @DavidK thanks for your appreciation. Equations come from an econ. paper of "Hyperbolic discounting and positive optimal inflation". They are presented as follows:
Government's budget constraint is
$$\chi = \frac{1}{N} \left( \tau\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{w}{(1+\pi)^i}n_i+m_t-\frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi}\right)$$

given initial wealth distribution:
$$c=\frac{r}{1+R(1-\xi_t)}\frac{1}{Nr}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\left[(1-\tau)w_t(i)n_t(i)+\chi_t \right]$$

substituting for government BC it yields:
$$c=\frac{1}{1+R(1-\xi_t)}\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\left[ w_t(i)n_t(i)+m_t-\frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi}\right]$$

Comment: The source you just quoted did not put the one summation itself in the other with the same index variable. You did that. Understand that $i$ is a dummy variable. That means $\chi$ is not dependent on a variable $i$. The $i$ only has definition within the scope of the summation, and changing $i$ to some other variable does affect the value in any way. That changing of variables is exactly what you should have done before substituting for $\chi$ in the other expression. Then there would have been no ambiguity in $i$.

Comment: It seems to me the paper is flawed. The formula for $\chi$ is ambiguous. Moreover, neither interpretation of the formula for $\chi$ leads to the final claimed result. Was the paper peer-reviewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what is happening, though there is some inconsistency in their notation that forces me to guess. First, I suspect that $n_t(i)$ and $n_i$ are the same thing. (Note that there is also an apparent equivalence between $\chi$ and $\chi_t$.)

Second, I think $$w_t(i) = \frac w{(1+\pi)^i}.$$

Third, as David K points out, the expression
$$\chi = \frac{1}{N} \left( \tau\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{w}{(1+\pi)^i}n_i+m_t-\frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi}\right)$$
must have a mistake in it. if the $m_t-\frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi}$ terms are supposed to be inside the summation, then they would be multiplied by $\tau$. If they are not included in the summation, then they are multiplied by $\frac 1N$ without having $N$ copies added together to cancel it. In either case, in the final result, they would have an extra multiplier of $\tau$ or $\frac 1N$ (in addition to one already there) that is not present. The authors appear to have interpreted the equation as either
$$\chi = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \left(\tau\frac{w}{(1+\pi)^i}n_i+m_t-\frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi}\right)$$
or, equivalently, as
$$\chi = \frac{1}{N} \left( \tau\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{w}{(1+\pi)^i}n_i\right)+m_t-\frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi}.$$
Neither of these is mathematically the same as what they wrote down. If you make the substitutions I indicated earlier in that last expression for $\chi$, you get

$$\chi = \frac 1N \left(\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \tau w_t(i)n_t(i)\right)+m_t-\frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi}$$

In their other equation, since $\chi_t$ is not dependent on $i$, the $N$ copies of it in the summation cancel the $\frac 1N$ multiplier and we get:
$$(1+R(1-\xi_t))c=\frac 1N\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\left[(1-\tau)w_t(i)n_t(i)+\chi_t \right] = \left[\frac 1N\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(1-\tau)w_t(i)n_t(i)\right]+\chi_t.$$
If you substitute for $\chi_t$ now, you no longer have one summation inside the other, so it is unnecessary to change summation variables:
$$(1+R(1-\xi_t))c=\left[\frac 1N\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(1-\tau)w_t(i)n_t(i)\right]+\frac 1N \left(\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \tau w_t(i)n_t(i)\right)+m_t-\frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi}$$
Since the two sums are over the exact same range of indices, we can combine them into one:
$$\begin{align}(1+R(1-\xi_t))c&=\left[\frac 1N\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(1-\tau)w_t(i)n_t(i) +\tau w_t(i)n_t(i)\right]+m_t-\frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi}\\
&=\left[\frac 1N\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}w_t(i)n_t(i)\right]+m_t-\frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi}
\end{align}$$
Bringing the $m_t-\frac{m_{t-1}}{1+\pi}$ back inside the summation in the same way it was brought out and dividing both sides by $(1+R(1-\xi_t))$ finishes converting the expression to the form you want.

Why $w_t(i) = \frac w{(1+\pi)^i}$ is something you will have to find elsewhere in the paper. I only guessed it because it is what makes this calculation work out.

Comment: It is not clear to me whether the authors just goofed writing out the equation for $\chi$ but had the correct interpretation, or if they made a mathematical error and their final equation is wrong. That is something else you'll have to figure out elsewhere.

Comment: I had a partial answer in the works, but I think this answer already says everything I would have said about the equations, as well as some things I probably would not have thought to say.

Comment: It starts to be very clear to me what was stucking me on the demonstration. Thank you very much @Paul for your interesting analysis, since you looked the paper and found a kind of inconsistency on the paper's equations showed in the appendix. I only made the direct substitution without considering this and thought I wasn't properly manipulating the summations, so that motivated my initial question. I'll be taking your answer as the solution, thanks! It's also intriguing to know what actually happened with the authors' equations, but that's another question that motivates to contact them.

Comment: @DavidK thanks for your contribution too, it was helpful!